# @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), no cubre bloque de catch(){}

Tags: java, spring, test, try-catch, mockito

Como puedo cubrir el bloque catch(){........} al realizar el test, estoy realizar un test con mockito.

La clase que estoy evaluando, es PRESR003Impl:

```
@Override
    public TransactionDTO executeServiceCardTransactionASO(String cardId, String TransId) {
        ListTransactionASO listTransactionASO = new ListTransactionASO();
        TransactionASO transactionASO = new TransactionASO();
        listTransactionASO.setData(Arrays.asList(transactionASO));

        LOGGER.info("[PRESR003Impl] - executeServiceCardTransactionASO(id) : {} - {}", cardId,TransId);
        TransactionDTO transactionDTO = null;

        try{
            ListTransactionASO transactions = this.chameleonConnector.getForObject(API_GET_TRANSACTION, ListTransactionASO.class, queryParams);

            if (transactions != null && !transactions.getData().isEmpty()) {
                TransactionASO aTransactionASO = transactions.getData().get(0);
                if(aTransactionASO != null){
                    transactionDTO = new TransactionDTO(aTransactionASO.getId(), aTransactionASO.getLocalAmount(), aTransactionASO.getTransactionType());
                }
            }
        }catch (RestClientException e){
            LOGGER.info("[PRESR003Impl] Error to connect ASO: {}", e.getMessage());
            this.addAdvice(ERROR_TO_CONNECT_SERVICE_CUSTOMERS);
        }
        return transactionDTO;
    }
```

El metodo que contiene el try-catch, es llamado aca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el metodo test que estoy implementano:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué método se supone lanza el `RestClientException`?

Comment: RestClientException, solo es una clase customizada que hera de NestedRuntimeException.

Comment: al realizar el test, puedo cubrir todo el codigo dentro del try{..}, pero no hayo como cubrir la parte del catch()

Comment: Por favor, pon el código como texto y no como imágenes. En todo caso en tu segundo test defines el mockup pero no invocas el método *executeServiceCardTransactionASO*

Comment: no me dejo publicar el post con esa parte como código, tuve que ponerlo en imagen, sorry

Comment: claro, asi lo invoco: TransactionDTO transactionDTO = presr003.executeServiceCardTransactionASO(cardId, transactionId);

Comment: pero mi inconveniente es realizar el assertTrows para evaluar el test, con @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) , para que cubra el bloque de catch(){}